# How to get all instance of an interface in .net core 1.0

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

In Mvc5 I use unity as service container and resolve all objects of a particular type using this ways.

```
    public IUnityContainer UnityContainer;

    public MvcApplication()
    {
        UnityContainer = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
    }


    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        foreach (var task in UnityContainer.ResolveAll<IRunAtInit>())
        {
            task.Execute();
        }
    }
```

In .net core using  default service container how can I resolve all objects of a particular type ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the [plural](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.cs#L88) version of the extension method.

Instead of `services.GetService<T>()` use `services.GetServices<T>()`.

If you want to inject them into a service, just inject `IEnumerable<IRunAtInit>` in the constructor.